# Error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character

Tags: kubernetes, wildcard, nginx-ingress, helm3

I want to set wildcard subdomain for my project, using k8s, nginx ingress controller, helm chart:

In `ingress.yaml` file:

```
...
rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
...
```

In `values.yaml` file, I change host `example.local` to `*.example.local`:

```
...
ingress:
  enabled: true
  host: "*.example.local"
...
```

Then, when I install chart using helm chart:

```
Error: YAML parse error on example/templates/ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character
```

How can I fix it?

Thank for your support.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

YAML treats strings starting with asterisk in a special way - that's why the hostname with wildcards like `*.example.local`  breaks the ingress on `helm install`.
In order to be recognized as strings, the values in `ingress.yaml` file should be quoted with  `" "` characters:

```yaml
...
rules:
  - host: "{{ .Values.ingress.host }}"
...
```

One more option here - adding `| quote` :

```yaml
...
rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host | quote }}
...
```

I've reproduced your issue, both these options worked correctly. More information on quoting special characters for YAML is [here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#53-indicator-characters).

Comment: Thank for your support. Your options worked

Answer (score 3):

In your `ingress.yaml` put quotes around the host key.

```
host: "{{ .Values.ingress.host }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### ingress:
enabled: true
host: "*.example.local"

you may need to use "---" instead of